# Zsh alternative to bash's quick assignment and inheritance trick

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables

There's a trick available in bash allowing you to set environment variable for child process and run it in single line, retaining original values of variable in the shell. For example, in order to set the "LANG" and "FOO" environment variables and then run "gedit", we would use the following command (from [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Bash.27s_quick_assignment_and_inheritance_trick)):

```
LANG=he_IL.UTF-8 FOO=bar gedit
```

It doesn't work in zsh.

Is there a similarly simple alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe works the same in Zsh as it does in Bash. From [the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Simple-Commands-_0026-Pipelines):

> A simple command is a sequence of optional parameter assignments followed by blank-separated words, with optional redirections interspersed. The first word is the command to be executed, and the remaining words, if any, are arguments to the command.
>
> If a command name is given, the parameter assignments modify the environment of the command when it is executed. (…)

… and [in Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion):

> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are saved for later processing.
>
> …
>
> If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell environment. Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment

Comment: I was testing it with `TEST=5 echo $TEST`, but I've now discovered that it doesn't work neither in zsh nor in bash (outputs nothing). In zsh, `echo` is builtin and it may explain why it doesn't work; however, what's wrong in case of bash?

Comment: I see. Read the Bash manual again: *"words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) […] are saved for later processing* – your `echo` command won't see the change of `$TEST`. Run `TEST=5 sh -c 'echo $TEST'` and see what happens!